# Не смотря на покупку отключения рекламы в приложении, реклама показывается. Как это исправить?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, in-app

Вот скрипт `IAPManager`, через который происходит покупка отключения рекламы!
 После покупки, кнопка не срабатывает, значит все сработало.

Видимо, я где-то напутал с проверкой того куплено ли отключение рекламы!
Делаю под android!

```
// Deriving the Purchaser class from IStoreListener enables it to receive messages from Unity Purchasing.
public class IAPManager : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener
{

    public static IAPManager Instance{set;get;}

    private static IStoreController m_StoreController;          // The Unity Purchasing system.
    private static IExtensionProvider m_StoreExtensionProvider; // The store-specific Purchasing subsystems.

    // public static string kProductIDConsumable =    "consumable";   
    // public static string kProductIDNonConsumable = "nonconsumable";
    public static string PRODUCT_NO_ADS =  "noads"; 

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        // If we haven't set up the Unity Purchasing reference
        if (m_StoreController == null)
        {
            // Begin to configure our connection to Purchasing
            InitializePurchasing();
        }
    }  
    public void InitializePurchasing() 
    {
        // If we have already connected to Purchasing ...
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            // ... we are done here.
            return;
        }

        // Create a builder, first passing in a suite of Unity provided stores.
        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());


        builder.AddProduct(PRODUCT_NO_ADS, ProductType.NonConsumable);

         UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
          }


    private bool IsInitialized()
    {
        // Only say we are initialized if both the Purchasing references are set.
        return m_StoreController != null && m_StoreExtensionProvider != null;
    }
    public void BuyNoAds()
    {
        BuyProductID(PRODUCT_NO_ADS);
    }

    private void BuyProductID(string productId)
    {
        // If Purchasing has been initialized ...
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            // ... look up the Product reference with the general product identifier and the Purchasing 
            // system's products collection.
            Product product = m_StoreController.products.WithID(productId);

            // If the look up found a product for this device's store and that product is ready to be sold ... 
            if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("Purchasing product asychronously: '{0}'", product.definition.id));
                // ... buy the product. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed 
                // asynchronously.
                m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);
            }
            // Otherwise ...
            else
            {
                // ... report the product look-up failure situation  
                Debug.Log("BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase");
            }
        }
        // Otherwise ...
        else
        {
            // ... report the fact Purchasing has not succeeded initializing yet. Consider waiting longer or 
            // retrying initiailization.
            Debug.Log("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
        }
    }      
    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        // Purchasing has succeeded initializing. Collect our Purchasing references.
        Debug.Log("OnInitialized: PASS");

        // Overall Purchasing system, configured with products for this application.
        m_StoreController = controller;
        // Store specific subsystem, for accessing device-specific store features.
        m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;
    }
    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        // Purchasing set-up has not succeeded. Check error for reason. Consider sharing this reason with the user.
        Debug.Log("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error);
    }
    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args) 
    {
        // A consumable product has been purchased by this user.
        if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, PRODUCT_NO_ADS, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            Debug.Log("No Ads");
        }
         else 
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: FAIL. Unrecognized product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
        }
        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
    }

    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureReason failureReason)
    {
        // A product purchase attempt did not succeed. Check failureReason for more detail. Consider sharing 
        // this reason with the user to guide their troubleshooting actions.
        Debug.Log(string.Format("OnPurchaseFailed: FAIL. Product: '{0}', PurchaseFailureReason: {1}", product.definition.storeSpecificId, failureReason));
    }
}
```

Вот сам показчик рекламы! Ставил и noads и `PRODUCT_NO_ADS` и даже NoAds, но реклама все равно показывает! И не через 5 проигрешей как у меня выставлена, а когда ей вздумаеться!

```
void Start ()
{
    ///Реклама
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("PRODUCT_NO_ADS") != "yes"){ //Должен проверять приобретено ли отключение рекламы! 
    if (Advertisement.isSupported)
        Advertisement.Initialize ("4794523", false);
    else
        Debug.Log ("Platform is not supported");
    }
}
```

Это срабатывает при проигрыше!

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("PRODUCT_NO_ADS") != "yes"){ //Должен проверять приобретено ли отключение рекламы! //
    advCount++;
    if (Advertisement.IsReady () && advCount % 5 == 0)
        Advertisement.Show ();              
}
```

Comment: PlayerPrefs PRODUCT_NO_ADS точно изменяется на в yes?

Comment: ProcessPurchase - где то тут при успешной покупке нужно сделать запись PlayerPrefs.SetString(PRODUCT_NO_ADS , "yes")

Comment: Если вам не сложно, можете мне подсказать как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо:

```
// A consumable product has been purchased by this user.
if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, PRODUCT_NO_ADS, StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
    Debug.Log("No Ads");
}
```

Напишите:

```
// A consumable product has been purchased by this user.
if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, PRODUCT_NO_ADS, StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
    Debug.Log("No Ads");
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(PRODUCT_NO_ADS , "yes");
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

И вместо:

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("PRODUCT_NO_ADS") != "yes"){ //Должен проверять приобретено ли отключение рекламы! //
    advCount++;
    if (Advertisement.IsReady () && advCount % 5 == 0)
        Advertisement.Show ();              
}
```

Напишите:

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetString (PRODUCT_NO_ADS) != "yes"){ //Должен проверять приобретено ли отключение рекламы! //
    advCount++;
    if (Advertisement.IsReady () && advCount % 5 == 0)
        Advertisement.Show ();              
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас попробую, отпишусь!

Comment: Вызвала подобную ошибку, о том что не обозначен контекст!  /Scripts/player.cs(82,30): error CS0103: The name `PRODUCT_NO_ADS' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @JonAlan `IAPManager.PRODUCT_NO_ADS`.

Comment: не доконца понял куда это указать!

Comment: Куда это указать? IAPManager.PRODUCT_NO_ADS, пробывал делать private static int IAPManager.PRODUCT_NO_ADS; но выдает ошибку!

Comment: @JonAlan туда, где ошибка "does not exist in the current context". Советую почитать что-нибудь базовое по C#, а уже потом браться за Unity.

Comment: @ Suvitruf Указал сюда, if (PlayerPrefs.GetString (IAPManager.PRODUCT_NO_ADS) != "yes") вроде я понял, спасибо еще раз!

Comment: @JonAlan вот и отлично. Заработало теперь всё?

Comment: Скомпилировал, сейчас закину проверю.

Comment: Увы не помогло! Все равно реклама включается!

Answer (score 0):

Перечитал внимательно ваш код, и второй ответ.

Что следует сделать по правильному. Разбейте проблему на 2. И отдельно их решайте. Проблема 1 -  игнорит но адс. Проблема 2 - не срабатывает один раз из пяти. Решите сначала проблему один, убрав или закомментив весь код по второй проблеме, и только тогда, когда уже не станет, добавляйте код по проблеме 2.

По первой проблеме, да, у вас в момент покупки делался только Debug.Log("No Ads"); и ничего не писалось в PlayerPrefs. Это точно надо исправить, как написано в соседнем ответе. С учетом исправления IAPManager.PRODUCT_NO_ADS из комментариев. Без этого NO_ADS точно работать не будет. И использовать Equals("yes") вместо = тоже не повредит.
В своем проекте я использовал при покупке

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("NoAds", 1);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

и при проверке

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("NoAds") != 1
```

По второй проблеме: по предоставленному куску кода вызова рекламы не ясно, сколько раз он вызывается. Может, этот кусок где то спамится прямо. В апдейте например, размещен. И тогда вы не заметите разницы, вызывается реклама один раз из пяти кадров, или просто каждый кадр.

Comment: Хорошо попробую, спасибо!

Comment: К сожалению не помогло! Есть ли у вас подобный скрипт только рабочий? Чтобы его изучить, может я где-то в коде ошибся?

Comment: @JonAlan, я подправил ответ. Отпишитесь, как проверите.

Comment: Может это важно, в google у меня стоит Идентификатор продукта - noads